# Using regexp_replace on array column in postgres

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I am trying to update all occurrences of some value in every element of an array column using a regexp.

If the column was not of type `text[]` and text instead I would use this query to update:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET my_column = regexp_replace(
    my_column, 'foo(\d+)', 'bar\1', 'g'
)
```

How can I replace each element in an array column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way as I know:

```
UPDATE my_table SET
  my_column = array(
    SELECT regexp_replace(unnest(my_column), 'foo(\d+)', 'bar\1', 'g'))
```

PostgreSQL too smart. It is possible to use SRF (set returning functions, just google it) as argument of other functions. For example:

```
select abs(unnest('{1,-2,3}'::int[]));
```

It is same to

```
select abs(x) from unnest('{1,-2,3}'::int[]) as x;
```

but shorter.

Its returning

```
┌─────┐
│ abs │
╞═════╡
│   1 │
│   2 │
│   3 │
└─────┘
```

And `array(select ...)` is just array constructor that transforms `select...` result to an array.

Answer (score 2):

Use a CTE to `unnest()` the array, do the transformation on the array elements and aggregate back to an array which you then use for the `UPDATE`. Assuming your table has a primary key:

```
WITH changed(key, arr) AS (
  SELECT id, array_agg(regexp_replace(col, 'foo(\d+)', 'bar\1', 'g'))
  FROM my_table, unnest(my_column) un(col)
  GROUP BY id
)
UPDATE my_table
SET my_column = arr
FROM changed
WHERE id = key
```